# PNG export with specific file size using ExtendScript for Adobe Illustrator

Tags: export, png, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to create a script in Extendscript that draws something and then exports the entire Artboard as a PNG in the size 4500x5400 px (or any other specific size).
This is the code I have right now:

```js
//create new document with my desired size     
var myDoc = app.documents.add();
myDoc.width = 4500;
myDoc.height = 5400;
    
//create a rectangle that is smaller than the artboard
var rect = myDoc.layers[0].pathItems.rectangle(700,300,72,100);

//export Image with name newImage.png (I have a specific path here) 
exportFileToPNG24 ("~/newImage.png");
    

function exportFileToPNG24(dest) {
  if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    exportOptions.artBoardClipping = true; //this option makes sure I export 
                                          //the whole artboard and not just 
                                          //the rectangle    
    var type = ExportType.PNG24;
    var fileSpec = new File(dest);
    
    app.activeDocument.exportFile(fileSpec, type, exportOptions);       
  }
}
```

The script does export the whole artboard as a png. But the PNG always has the size 612x792 px. How can I get it to export in 4500x5400 px?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
var myDoc = app.documents.add();
myDoc.width = 4500;
myDoc.height = 5400;
```

It makes sense to create a new document this way:

```
var preset    = app.getPresetSettings("Web");
preset.units  = RulerUnits.Pixels;
preset.width  = 4500;
preset.height = 5400;
var myDoc     = app.documents.addDocument("Web", preset);
```

Or you can make a new document with default size and then change it this way:

```
var myDoc = app.documents.add();
myDoc.artboards[0].artboardRect = [0,5400,4500,0];
```